# Mongoose can't find and update my document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my mongo I have document

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("56658b4b9f41447c29f8d78e"),
    "hostname": "VSX-01",
    "time": "15:03:11",
    "day": "7",
    "con": [
    "100000",
    "4994",
    "9",
    "19904",
    "7772",
    "13323",
    "245",
    "14",
    "221"
    ],
    "cpu": [
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "102",
    "20",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0"
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

and like to find and update it using mongoose query below, nothing happens, prints

```
 var newMessage = new Message(conmessage);               
    console.log(conmessage);  /* Prints { hostname: 'VSX-01',
  cpu: [ 0, 0, 0, '102', '20', 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  con: [ '100000', '4994', '9', '19904', '7772', '13323', '245', '14', '221' ],
  time: '15:03:11',
  day: '7' }*/

    newMessage.find({'time': conmessage.time},  //findOneAndUpdate
        function(err, message) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(message);
        })
```

My schema var messageSchema = new Schema({hostname: String, cpu: [String], con: [String], time: String, day: String});

Comment: Do you want to create newMessage with conmessage then then want to find that newMessage by later? or anything please explain.

Comment: I receive new message in variable 'conmessage' and want to find if message with the same 'time' is already in db. I was using 'findOneAndUpdate' but simplified it to 'find' only for the moment. newMessage.save works fine...just not any newMessage.find...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please give your schema ? I dont check this code, but i think this will help you.
You can try with this code :

```
Message.find({'time' : conmessage.time },
    function(err, message) {
      if (err)
        throw err;
      else if(message){
        console.log("Message already exists");

      }
      else{
        var newMessage = new Message(conmessage);
      }
    });
```